# how to make ovh run my website from index.html and not index.php?

Tags: php, html, ovh

i change an already existing website who is hosting by OVH

there was a little bit of php but i changed it because the website doesn't need a back-end server to run, front-end javascript is good enough
I would like the web site to start with my index.html file because the index.php doesn't need to exist anymore, but I don't know how to do that

I tried to remove the .htaccess and the .ovhconfig because i thought they was usefull only for the php, and it broke nothing (good to begin) but it doesn't helped for my problem

the .ovhconfig content :

```
app.engine=php
app.engine.version=5.4
http.firewall=none
environment=production
```

the .htaccess content :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_TEST
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
```

(there is another .htacess file with the same content in the parent folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your .htaccess:

`DirectoryIndex index.html`

As it's described here: https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/hosting/what_else_can_you_do_with_the_htaccess_file/

Comment: it doesn't work... i tried to put in both the .htaccess present on the parent and subparent folder

Comment: actually i don't know what happened but whole website doesn't work anymore and i can't come back to when it worked ??

Comment: I don't see one. the title of the page warn me of an error 500

Comment: Show me your modified .htaccess file content

Comment: I put it back to it's original content but it still don't work (original content is the one you see in my original post)

Comment: it's weird, what can have i done to create an error 500 ?

Comment: well i'm in deep shit now the website doesn't work anymore and i don't know what to do !! have you an idea where I can ask for help about that ?

Comment: There are some things you can do to find the error: 1- backup your index.php and replace it's contents with "hello!". Do you still receive error 500? If not, it's an error in your php file (i bet that's the case). 2- backup and remove your .htaccess files. Still receive error 500? If not, you now know where the error is. 3- find your error log file. If you're in a Unix-like Operational System, it should be located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Not there? The correct path should be described at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. When you find it, it should have an description of what's going on

Comment: i kind of fixed it... i renamed .htaccess in .htaccess_bak

Comment: Are you sure you have restored your .htaccess file to the original content? I'm glad it's working anyway

Comment: I really think i did. now, i can put your line to ask for the index.html, but as soon as i rename the .htaccess_bak to a .htaccess it gives me an error500 again. I will let it with the name_back then, even though i don't understand what's happening

Comment: then, thank you for the help, your answer is the good one, i don't know what happened !